# What do I modify to stop light dm from starting at boot

Tags: boot, lightdm

I installed MATE and lightdm and then set them to to start automatically

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default graphical
$ sudo systemctl start lightdm
$ reboot
```

System is now stuck trying to start light manager with no time out limit on the service timeout.

I believe I failed to install lightdm greeter!!!

Ctrl-AltF[1-12] don't achieve anything because the login/logon service has not yet started.

I have another system where I can mount the drive and make changes.

What do I edit in order to set the system back to multi-user mode in the same way that:

```
$ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
```

does?

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details, why make us guess?

Answer (score 0):

#### `multi-user.target`

What

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

does is remove the file(*symbolic link*):

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

then create this symbolic link:

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target --> /lib/systemd/system/multi-uaer.target
```

which you can manually do with:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

then:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/multi-uaer.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

#### `graphical.target`

And what

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

does is remove the file(*symbolic link*):

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

then create this symbolic link:

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target --> /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target
```

which you can manually do with:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

then:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

Comment: Looked in that directory (/etc/...).  I can see another dir "default.target.wants" (not a link) but nothing just "default.target".  I did find it under /lib/systemd/system.  SO I changed that symbolic and rebooted but it still is trying to start lightdm.  Simpler at this stage to re-install!!!